# How to regard an Iwasawa algebra $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ as a disk?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

> **UPDATE**: I have posted this question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447558/geometric-interpretation-of-iwasawa-algebras-mathbbz-pt-as-a-disk/447570?noredirect=1#comment1156728_447570) and obtained two answers.

I am a student learning Iwasawa theory. A quite basic object is the Iwasawa algebra. A basic version is as follows:

Let $L/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be a finite extension (i.e. a local number field) where $p$ is a prime (if necessary, we may assume $p \geq 3$ or $p \geq 5$.) Let $\mathcal{O}_L$ be its ring of integer. Then we define $\Lambda := \mathcal{O}_L[[T]]$ as the ring of formal power series of one indeterminate $T$ with $\mathcal{O}_L$-coefficient, called an **Iwasawa algebra**.

I have see in many papers that people regard $\Lambda$ as a **disk**, or regard the "**rational Iwasawa algebra**" $\Lambda_{\mathbb{Q}}:= \Lambda \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} \mathbb{Q}_p$ (I am still wondering if this is correct, as a tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}_p$?) as a disk. Moreover, people often say that some kind of a $p$-adic L-function $\mathcal{L}_p$ is in the disk, and **"a small neighborhood"** of the $\mathcal{L}_p$ satisfies certain properties.

**MY QUESTION**: How to make such statements precise? In other words, how can people view the Iwasawa algebra as a disk, talk about its elements as points and the neighboorhood of the points.

Moreover, quite [recently](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.09806), there is a notion called **"shrinked Iwasawa algebra"** $\Lambda_{m}:= \mathcal{O}_L[[p^{-m}T]] \subset \Lambda$. The author stated that this can be regarded as shrinking the disk into smaller radius, just as the name shows.

**My further question**: How do people regard this "shrinked Iwasawa algebra" as a disk of smaller radius?

Put a step further, in more applications, we may consider $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions $\mathcal{K}_{\infty}/\mathcal{K}$ of Galois group $\mathbb{Z}_p^d$ for $d > 1$. Then the corresponding Iwasawa algebra should be $\Lambda_{(d)} := \mathcal{O}_L[[T_1, \ldots, T_d]]$. Then

**Can we also regard $\Lambda_{(d)}$ as some kind of disk** and further generalize the "shrinked Iwasawa algebra"?

Thank you all for commenting and answering! Any references on explaining these are also welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me take a detour.

Consider the category of complex analytic spaces. We can construct the category of *analytic germs* as follows. The objects of this category are pairs $(X,x)$, where $X$ is a complex analytic space and $x \in X$. Consider two objects $(X,x)$ and $(Y,y)$. Let $U$ and $V$ be two open neighbourhoods of $x$ in $X$, and $f: U \to Y$, $g: V \to Y$ two analytic maps mapping $x$ to $y$. We say $f$ and $g$ are equivalent if there exists an open neighbourhood $W$ of $x$ contained in $U \cap V$ such that $f|_W = g|_W$. A morphism from $(X,x)$ to $(Y,y)$ in the category of germs will be an equivalence class of this relation.

Note that two germs $(X,x)$ and $(Y,y)$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ and an open neighbourhood $V$ of $y$ in $Y$ which are isomorphic. In particular, if $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$, then $(X,x)$ and $(U,x)$ are canonically isomorphic. Therefore, the germ $(X,x)$ should be thought as an infinitesimal neighbourhood of $x$.

Given a germ $(X,x)$, we can consider the local ring of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. It is an analytic $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, i.e. a quotient of a ring of convergent power series $\mathbb{C}\{z_1,\dots,z_n\}$. This establishes a contravariant equivalence of categories between the category of analytic germs and analytic algebras. If you want more details about this, see Remark 1.47.1(2) in the book *Introduction to Singularities and Deformations* by Greuel, Lossen and Shustin.

Consider the germ $(\mathbb{C},0)$. As it is mentioned above, it should be thought as an infinitesimal disk around $0$. According to the equivalence of categories described before, $(\mathbb{C},0)$ corresponds to the analytic $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $\mathbb{C}\{z\}$.

When we have an abstract field $k$ there is no notion of convergent power series, but we can still consider the ring of *formal* power series, denoted by $k[ \! [t ] \! ]$. Therefore, if we move from the category of analytic germs to the realm of formal geometry, $\mathrm{Spf} \ k[ \! [t ] \! ]$ should be thought as an infinitesimal formal disk.

This applies to your case when $k = \mathbb{Q}_p$. In turn, $\mathrm{Spf} \ \mathbb{Z}_p[ \! [t ] \! ]$ is a formal model of $\mathrm{Spf} \ \mathbb{Q}_p[ \! [t ] \! ]$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Finally, the analytic germ $(\mathbb{C}^n,0)$ corresponds to the $\mathbb{C}$-analytic algebra $\mathbb{C}\{z_1,\dots,z_n\}$. Thefore, given a field $k$, $\mathrm{Spf} \ k[ \! [t_1,\dots,t_n ] \! ]$ should be thought as a formal polydisk.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't have realized that there are so many interpretations on $\Lambda$. A classical approach as functions over open unit disks (by D. Loeffler), generalization from rigid analytic geometry (by Alexey Do) and your answer on formal geometry. Thank you so much and it could be a starting point for me to learn something on these stuff. :)

Comment: @HetongXu I've just realised you also posted the question on MathOverflow. Nice answers indeed!